# ubuntu crash problem

Tags: unity

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04.

I accidently removed `libpng` from the system and after that I'm not able to get to my desktop. Everytime I restart the system, after Ubuntu logo all is the login screen and after that I can only access the virtual terminals but I'm unable to get my desktop.

What should I do to get back to my desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If all that you did to break the system was remove libpng, you could go out to a virtual console and type sudo apt-get install libpng (if it can't find the package name, try searching for it with sudo apt-cache search libpng and note the name of the package with the right library.